# Spring @RequestBody REST services post method return 415 in some entity relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-java-config

I am working with spring rest and hibernate. 
I checked stackoverflow these linkes but they did not solve my issue!

[Spring MVC 3.1 REST services post method return 415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222681/spring-mvc-3-1-rest-services-post-method-return-415)

[415 Unsupported MediaType for POST request in spring application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066591/415-unsupported-mediatype-for-post-request-in-spring-application)

[HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type when doing POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204614/http-status-415-unsupported-media-type-when-doing-post)

and so more post ..

When I have this kind of relation in my entities, there is no problem in post and @RequestBody

University.java

```
public class University extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String telephon;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "university", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();
// setter an getter
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "SECTION")
    private String section;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIVERSITY_ID",nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private University university;

// setter an getter
    }
```

But when I add Certificate entity to my relation like below

Edited:

Student.java

```
public class Student extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "SECTION")
    private String section;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIVERSITY_ID",nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private University university;

   // added new relation
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "certificateid",nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Certificate certificate;


// setter an getter
    }
```

Certificate.java

```
public class Certificate extends BaseEntity{

     private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "certificate")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Student> students=new ArrayList<>();
    // setter an getter
}
```

In this type of relations I encounter the **415 error**. and in some post it is suggested to use @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestBody, and it solve the error. But due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716767/spring-mvc-requestbody-vs-modelattribute) post, it says it is proper to use in MVC, not in rest template.

my controller api is:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/create3", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<University> create3( @RequestBody University model) throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<University>(this.universityService.add(model), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and my config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
public class moduleConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Hibernate5Module module = new Hibernate5Module();
        module.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);

        mapper.registerModule(module);

        //Some other configuration....

        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
//configure the output json format
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823358/spring-configure-responsebody-json-format
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter c = (AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = c.getObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            }
        }

        super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(this.jacksonBuilder().build());

    return converter;
}

public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    Hibernate5Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();

    hibernateModule.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);

    builder.modules(hibernateModule);

    // Spring MVC default Objectmapper configuration
    builder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    builder.featuresToDisable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

    return builder;
}



@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}



}
```

}

1.How Entities relation cause problem in my post method?

2.what I am missing in my code to do it correctly?

any help and idea appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the Json send to server please? And does the server throws an exception? if yes add it too

Comment: {
"name":"name",
"address":"address",
"telephon":"telephon"
}

Comment: I added the postman picture

Comment: No stack trace on the server side? Anyway Jackson doesn't support multiple @JsonBackReference on one entity without naming them (i guess that's why it stopped working when you added the second one). Try adding an unique name per relation

Comment: @ Baptiste Beauvais thanks for your great comment, It worked after giving name for each on.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson doesn't support multiple `@JsonBackReference` on one entity class without naming them specifically (every relating have a default name given).

Set a specific name for each relation like:

```
@JsonManagedReference(value = "a_name")

@JsonBackReference(value = "a_name")
```

The problem comes from the format of the JSON (and any document oriented data) that doesn't allow multiple parent for one node.